# How to add token authentication in the headers with interceptor and the token can be null?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have Application Angular13 with authentication OAuth and I try to add this token for all services.

But I don't manage undefined token.
I have tried several techniques for calling the token but I always end up with an error, I want to be able to use non-authenticate services anyway

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const  {token}  = this.authService.decodedAccessToken;
    if (token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

i add this on ngModel

```
providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
    multi: true,
  },],
```

try this

```
const  token  = this.authService.decodedAccessToken;
// or this
typeof token != 'undefined' && token
// no condition
Authorization: `Bearer ${this.authService.decodedAccessToken}`,
// and on error 401
 this.authService.logout();
//
return next.handle(request):
```

```
angular-oauth2-oidc.mjs:1398 error loading discovery document TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'token' of 'this.authService.decodedAccessToken' as it is undefined.
/// or 
core.mjs:6509 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'message')
/// or
status: 401
```

I currently have blank pages or incomplete loading

Comment: So to be clear, you want to bypass your http token interceptor service for certain non authenticated calls ? Use certain non authenticated services with our without token ?

Comment: yes that's it I want to add the token if it exists

Comment: What is the error?  And what is on the http request?  Does it add auth header and if so what is in it?

Comment: [Don't use bearer tokens in web applications](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/asp-net-core-angular-xsrf-62c3833fd1fe)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const token  = this.authService.decodedAccessToken?.token || null;
```

Comment: does not work it is always null

Comment: const  token = this.authService.decodedAccessToken? this.authService.decodedAccessToken:null;